# Odoo 10 - New field in send sale order by email wizard form

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

In the sale order view, there is a "Send offer by email" button which launches the email wizard.

I would like to add the "CC" carbon copy email field in that form.
I am not sure on how to add it, did anyone faced the same need?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can add your own BCC CC by customizing the wizard

Refer this module for more details:

**https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/base_smtp_auto_CC_BCC/**

Comment: Thanks, I am sure that it is easy but I am facing issues on where shall be included the new field in the wizard. The module does not include anything related to that as it just adds automatically CCs and BCCs. Could you please further elaborate on how to add it to the wizard?